# Scoot airlines in European Union-Schengen

Tags: schengen, scoot

Has anyone flown with Scoot within the European Union? I have only travelled between Schengen countries and a national ID card is the only entry requirement. Scoot sent me an email saying a passport is required, which I find terribly misinformed. It's a flight between Athens and Berlin. Can they enforce this and deny me boarding with ID card?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Scoot. Did you manage to board the plane just with your ID?

Comment: I'm surprised they actually sell tickets on that segment given the complications of having intra-Schengen passengers on an international flight. Did you fly already? How did things go? Did you go through passport control in ATH and BER?

Comment: @jcaron is it so complicated?  They either run the flight as an internal flight (making through passengers go through passport control in Athens) or they run it as an external flight (making passengers between Athens and Berlin go through passport control in both places as specified in annex VI point 2.1.2(b)(iii) of the Schengen Borders Code).  Yes it's added complication, but probably not so much complication as to justify forgoing the extra revenue.

Comment: @phoog from what I can see (departure gate in BER), the "internal" flight uses ex-Schengen gates, so it's probably the second option. Didn't know the Schengen Borders Code actually planned for this (though they only mention the ATH-BER case in this situation, while Scoot also sell the BER-ATH flight, but I suppose the procedure is the same even though it's not listed in the Code). I wonder how frequent this situation is. Frequent enough to require an entry in the Code I suppose. Indeed for the airline itself it's not a problem, but it may raise issues for quite a few of their passengers.

Comment: I'm flying tomorrow with Scoot from Athens to Berlin as well. 2 of my friends who've done this exact flight with Scoot, reassured me that they didn't have a problem. Except for the fact that they can't check in online. Out of stress I messaged Scoot and they replied back saying that I'm going to be needing a passport, but the email wasn't that clear. I don't have a passport, I am a EU citizen has anyone flew with them recently? I doubt they can deny me entry but I don't want to risk it as well.

Comment: You always need to have a passpot or ID on you when traveling internationally, even within Schengen. But I suspect that you will not have to go through passport control. There was for a time a 5th freedom flight Zurich - Prague with China Southern, and that flight boarded from the Schengen concourse.

Comment: Delta Oni, how did it go with your flight? Everything ok with online check in and ID card at the gate? My flight is in April.

Answer (score 9):

> Scoot sent me an email saying a passport is required, which I find terribly misinformed

It can happen that the flight you're taking is a connecting flight from outside Schengen, and therefore is parked in the non-Schengen zone of the airport, therefore requiring you to pass passport control, leave Schengen and re-enter in Berlin. Therefore inducing possible misconceptions

This seems to be the case with Scoot TR720 which is a Singapore-Athens-Berlin flight

Of course, you do not need a passport if you are a EU/EFTA/Swiss citizen to enter Germany, as laid out by @phoog in their answer

Comment: Good point. Scoot says that all its tickets are point-to-point (but also says "Unless otherwise specified, after disembarking from your arriving flight, you must clear Customs and Immigration, collect your checked baggage (if any), and then proceed to the relevant departure hall to check in for your connecting flight," leaving room for exceptions). It seems that Athens is a stop on the flight between Singapore and Berlin in both directions. If they don't disembark and reboard all of the passengers, this would have significant consequences for non-EU passengers, e.g. with single-entry visas.

Comment: @phoog I think some airlines do not disembark everyone, and I remember some answers where that got tricky with single-entry visas. But usually the exit is just cancelled by border officials at the next entry point

Comment: I know that some airlines don't; I've been on a few such flights.  My question is what Scoot does with this flight; it's not clear from their website -- and whether the immigration agents in Athens and Berlin have a line of communication in place for cancelling exit stamps of passengers on the flight with limited entry visas.

Comment: Scoot disembarks everyone in Athens

Comment: @njzk2 but do they send everyone through passport control at that point?

Comment: @jcaron IIRC passport check is (in the BER -> ATH direction) in Berlin

Comment: @njzk2 for intra-Schengen passengers (i.e., flying between Athens and Berlin in either direction) there must be either two passport checks (one exit and one entry) or none.  If there are two, then passengers between Singapore and Berlin would not have to clear passport control in Athens even if they are disembarked; conversely, if Singapore-Berlin passengers do go through passport control in Athens then the Athens-Berlin leg would be internal, and intra-Schengen passengers would not go through passport control.  This seems unlikely given the context of the question.

Comment: @phoog you're right, now that I think of it I remember a second passport check in Athens

Answer (score 7):

On their [page for travel information](https://www.flyscoot.com/en/plan/before-you-fly/travel-information), they don't even mention the word "passport"; they make it very clear that travel documentation is entirely the traveler's responsibility:

> Entry Requirements for Independent Travellers
>
> Whenever you travel, it is your responsibility to ensure that you are in possession of valid travel documentation and meet the entry requirements for all points of travel, including the country or countries you are visiting or transiting through. We recommend that you check with the relevant local authorities or tourism associations on the necessary entry requirements before your trip.

On the [planning your trip page](https://www.flyscoot.com/en/plan/before-you-fly/planning-your-trip), they only link to [IATA Travel Centre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com).

As a non-European airline, they likely employ a lot of people who are unfamiliar with the status of national identity cards in the EU and the Schengen area.  Even if the author of the e-mail message is aware, it would be an easy thing to overlook when writing a communication for passengers of an airline that seems to have only one intra-Schengen route.

The staff handling flights in Berlin and Athens, however, will surely be aware, and you will surely have no trouble.

> Can they enforce this and deny me boarding with ID card?

Probably not.  As a private company, they have certain leeway to decide who they do business with, but as a common carrier they have certain obligations, for example, they probably cannot discriminate on the basis of race (I'm being a bit vague here because I don't know the details of the relevant EU law; I'm more familiar with these technicalities in the US).

In any event, if you're denied boarding solely because you presented an ID instead of a passport then you would be [entitled to compensation](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#deniedBoarding), because regardless of the airline's policy, a national ID card is "correct documentation" as far as EU law is concerned.  If somehow the ground staff you're dealing with is unaware of this, you will want to bring it to their attention.  But the chance of this happening is pretty low.

Comment: While most likely 100% correct, it seems like such a minor inconvenience to pack the passport "just in case" than to deal with a denied boarding and all the hassles of trying to get to the destination (in time) and get a refund for the denied flight. It's like walking across the street - you may have the legal right of way, but if the car's not stopping, it's winning the fight; I'd rather be wronged than dead...

Comment: @FreeMan you are assuming OP has a passport, which isn't obvious. If you have ever only traveled in europe, never leaving the Schengen zone, it is highly possible you don't have a passport and have no idea how to get one, especially if your country has an ID document you have been relying on for all your local ID needs.

Comment: Good point, @bracco23, I did make that assumption. Most Americans probably don't have one either since we don't need one for interstate travel, either. Assuming that my assumption was correct (thus compounding the potential error :D ), I think carrying it would be prudent in this case...

Comment: Thanx everyone for their input. Indeed, I don't have a passport as I haven't travelled outside of Europe yet. Can't wait for your help once I begin having passport problems internationally 